# Error getting list from class

Tags: c#, list, class, ienumerable

I've created this class:

```
class Riconoscimento
{
    private List<Word> words = new List<Word>();


    public List<Word> GetList()
    {
        return words;
    }

    public void loadWords()
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/../../words.txt");
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                // skip commentblocks and empty lines..
                if (line.StartsWith("--") || line == String.Empty) continue;

                // split the line
                var parts = line.Split(new char[] { '|' });

                // add commandItem to the list for later lookup or execution
                words.Add(new Word() { Text = parts[0], AttachedText = parts[1], IsShellCommand = (parts[2]) });


            }
      }
}
```

But after loading *loadWords()* when I try to get the words from the class in my *MainForm* with

```
 public void engine_WordsRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        Riconoscimento _riconoscimento = new Riconoscimento();
        List<Word> words = _riconoscimento.GetList();
        var cmd = words.Where(c => c.Text == e.Result.Text).First();
}
```

This error occour:
  **System.InvalidOperationException -Sequence does not contain elements.**

It's like it can't retrieve the words from the class, I can't understand why. 
If I don't use the class but put everything in my main code it works. 
What should I do?

**Problem solved**: I loaded *loadWords()* in my other void, I had to load it inside my other void.

Comment: The list is empty.  Set a breakpoint inside `loadWords()` and make sure your words are getting loaded.

Comment: I understand it's empty but I don't know why. If I use this loadWords inside my mainForm instead of the class while also creating the List in my main form it works.

Comment: in your engine_WordsRecognized you are creating a new (local) instance of Riconoscimento and call GetList(), without calling loadWords on it: its internal words list is still empty

Answer (score 2):

You aren't calling `loadWords()`.  That's why nothing is being loaded.

```
public void engine_WordsRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    Riconoscimento _riconoscimento = new Riconoscimento();
    _riconoscimento.loadWords();
    List<Word> words = _riconoscimento.GetList();
    var cmd = words.Where(c => c.Text == e.Result.Text).First();
}
```

Comment: He said "after loading loadWords()"

Comment: I call it in my other void, inside mainForms. Have I to call it again inside this one ?

Comment: you should call on the instance that's newly created.

Answer (score 1):

That error is coming form the call to `First`.  You are not calling `loadWords` after creating the `Riconoscimento`, so the list never gets populated.  If you have another instance somewhere that already has the data loaded, then you may be able to use it, or you could also make `words` static if it will be the same for *every* instance.

Also, if the list may not contain the value you're looking for then `FirstOrDefault` will return `null` rather than throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You dont call `loadWords`. you just get a empty list from this property.

```
public List<Word> GetList()
{
    return words;
}
```

you have to call loadWords before getting property.

```
_riconoscimento.loadWords();
```

Or call it from inside property.

```
private List<Word> words = null; // initialize new list list inside loadWords

public List<Word> GetList()
{
    if(words == null) loadWords();
    return words;
}
```

Comment: there are many ways to do it. another way is to make this call inside constructor. i dont know how often (when) this method should be called. but when OP got his problem he can choose the best way for himself. @Steve